# Runtime error on test 1 (Codeforces)

Tags: c++, c++11

Using the link below

http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/556/B

The code below using the GNU C++11 compiler and that code is working fine 
but I do not know how it works?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<windows.h>
int test(long int n,long int number[])
{
    int flag=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(number[i+1]==number[i]+1)
            flag++;
    }
    if(flag==n-1)
       return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
void rot_gears(long int n,long int number[])
{
    system("cls");
    int t;
    for(long z=0;z<n*n;z++)
    {
        for(long i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(i%2==0)
            {
                if(number[i]==n-1)
                {
                    number[i]=0;
                }
                else
                    number[i]++;
            }
            else if(i%2!=0)
            {
                if(number[i]==0)
                    number[i]=n-1;
                else
                    number[i]--;
            }
        }
         t=test(n,number);
        if(t==1)
            break;

      // output(n,number);
       //cout<<"\n\n";
    }
    if(t)
        std::cout<<"YES";
    else
        std::cout<<"NO";
}
int main()
{
    long int n,teeth,number[10000];
    std::cin>>n;
    std::cin>>teeth;
    for(long int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)

    {
        number[i]=teeth%10;
        teeth/=10;
    }

    // output(n,number);
    rot_gears(n,number);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: this belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's no way to execute `system("cls");` on the judge machine - just remove that from the code.

Also you go out of bounds here when `i == n - 1`:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(number[i+1]==number[i]+1)
    //       ^^^^^ here
```

Though technically you don't go out of array bounds because `n <= 1000`, but anyway you're accessing uninitialized array element.

Comment: So what do I do about it?

Comment: @ArpitJoshi About what?

Comment: Okay so i removed the system("cls") 

Now instead of giving me runtime error it says wrong answer :P

It runs properly when I do it myself! 
I Dont know what is happening.

Comment: @ArpitJoshi this is beyond this question (and offtopic on SO). BTW anyway I showed you another possible source of error.